# java assist newbie question

Tags: java, javassist

I am trying to generate some classes on the fly, and the following is my initial attempt:

```
  ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
    cp.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(Main.class));
    CtClass entity = cp.makeClass("Entity");
    try {
        CtField id = new CtField(CtClass.intType, "id", entity);

        entity.addField(id);
        entity.addField(CtField.make(" public String name;", entity));
        entity.addMethod(CtNewMethod.make("public void say() { System.out.println(12222);}",entity));
        Class EntityClass = entity.toClass();
        entity.writeFile("/tmp");
        Object e=  EntityClass.newInstance();
        Field name = EntityClass.getField("name");
        name.set("Ooldooz", e);
        System.out.println(name.get(e));
    } catch (CannotCompileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

But I face a class loader issue:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field Entity.name to java.lang.String
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:37)
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)
>       at Main.test(Main.java:26)

Any ideas on how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

[Field#set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) takes the object as the first parameter and the value as the second.

You are calling it the other way around.

Change it to `name.set(e, "Ooldooz");`